# What is the default controller in Yii2 framework?

Tags: php, yii2

How to find the `default controller in Yii2` when `defaultRoute` isn't set but the application frontend is working fine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out finally. Try echoing `Yii::$app->defaultRoute` somewhere in your view file or controller action.

```
echo Yii::$app->defaultRoute;
```

According to [official documentation on Yii2 Controller](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/structure-controllers.md) on Default Controller:

Each application has a default controller specified via the yii\base\Application::defaultRoute property. When a request does not specify a route, the route specified by this property will be used. For [yii\web\Application|Web applications](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/web/Application.php), its value is `'site'`, while for [yii\console\Application|console](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/console/Application.php) applications, it is `'help'`.

Therefore, if a URL is http://hostname/index.php, then the '`site`' controller will handle the request.

Also, You may change the default controller with the following application configuration:

```
[
    'defaultRoute' => 'main',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The default value for `defaultRoute` is `site` in Yii2, as defined in the file `framework/web/Application.php`